# WPF - ScrollViewer returns to start position

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I have a table with cells, where values can be inserted. Table is generated dynamically, based on data. Table size is limited by the grid, where it is located. If data is too much, then appears a horizontal scroll bar.

This is implemented with ItemsControl in the ScrollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SomeCellRowSize"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SomeCellRowSize"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBox
                                        Text="{Binding Value.TotalTime}"
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Margin="1,1,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The problem happens, when we scroll the table to the right and select some cell (TextBox). If we do this, then ScrollViewer will return to the most left position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to have an integrated `ScrollViewer` inside the `ItemsPanel` itself than wrapping a `ScrollViewer` around it. From my experience, you tend to have more issues. Update your `Template` to have the `ScrollViewer` instead.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Value}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SomeCellRowSize"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="SomeCellRowSize"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBox
                                    Text="{Binding Value.TotalTime}"
                                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" BorderThickness="0" Margin="1,1,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: This helped us solve our issue with a `ScrollViewer` always resetting to the top. Thank you.

Comment: @B-Rad glad this can still help people 7 years later =]